# how to handle route param changes to component using @connect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux

I've got a Route which matches on something like `/roles/:id` and renders into the right hand pane (see below). I'm using `@connect` to pass some props and actions into my component, and one of those actions fetches some data based on the route param `id` in the `componentWillMount` hook.

My problem is that I can't think of a clean way to make sure that when a user clicks a different instance on the right hand list, thus changing the route (but not un/mounting the component!), the action is fired again.

[image: Layout]

I've thought of hooking into `componentWillReceiveProps`, but obviously that will create an infinite rendering loop. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why would hooking into `componentWillReceiveProps` create an infinite loop ? You just have to check the route param has changed : `if (this.props.routeParam !== nextProps.routeParam) fetchData(nextProps.routeParam)`

Comment: @vonD falls over on first render with a pageload though

Comment: on first render you can use `componentWillMount` the way you already do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 ways to do it

1- use decorator pattern to fetch data, [redux-async-connect](https://github.com/Rezonans/redux-async-connect)

2- use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) like this

```
export function fetchFoo(id) {
 return dispatch => {
   dispatch({type:'LOADING'});
   fetch(`/book/${id}`, (response) => {
     if(response.status == 200){
       dispatch({type:'SUCCESS'});
     }else { 
       dispatch({type:'FAIL'});
     }
   })
 }
}
```

initial state should be `loading=true`, `isLoaded=true`

in the `LOADING` reducer you should set `loading=true` in your state
and check `loading` flag before trigger `fetchFoo` action
in this way you will not have infinite requests

```
componentWillReceiveProps:(nextProps){
  if(!nextProps.loading && !nextProps.isLoaded){
    fetchFoo(params);
  }
}
```

i prepfer first solution use `decorator-pattern` for container componenets

Comment: Although I don't really like directly fetching data with the component that way (and thus keeping it in a different place to the global state atom's "namespaced" data) it does solve the problem. Thanks!